# Disallow anonymous users to access Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I have installed Sonar 3.5.1 and want to disable anonymous users access to the web console.
I went to Security page and deleted Anyone from users and codeviewers roles.
However, when I visit the web console without authentication I am still able to see "Welcome to Sonar Dashboard" page, whereas I expected to be redirected to the login page.

Is it possible to completely disallow unauthenticated users to see any content except the login page?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can set the "sonar.forceAuthentication" to "true" in the web admin interface:

[image: Administration > Configuration > General Settings > Security]

See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authentication for more details.