# How to setup project level permissions in sonar

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

Sonar Server 6.7.1.

I have following queries wrt how permission works in SonarQube
1. How to enable window NT authentication on sonar portal. I believe by default it is open to everybody, no authentication.

2. Using sonar admin account I can create the quality profiles (add/remove rules) & assign it to a project. Can I do it as project admin account as well? My use case is I have couple of projects hosted, I do not want to share admin account with each project.
3. I created many users and groups on sonar portal, but I could not see them under Global Permission page. How to projet administrators?
4. Let's say I have set of issues reported by sonar for a project. From the portal I want to mark some of the issues as "Won't fixed". What is the minimal permission required user/project admin/sonar admin to do it?

Appreciate your response on above queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Disable anonymous access: [Disallow anonymous users to access Sonar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825331/disallow-anonymous-users-to-access-sonar)
2. You need Administer Quality Gates global permission
3. You have to start typing username you are looking for in Search field
4. You need Administer Issues project permission

Please take a look at SonarQube documentation: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization